# JQuery clone() and append()

Tags: jquery, html, dom, clone

I have a simple table:

```
<table id='table_actions'">
    <tbody class='actions_body'>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2 class="taskname"><strong>1. </strong><span name='taskname'>name</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Действие: </td>
            <td>
                <select name='action_action'>
                    <option value="1">Consult</option>
                    <option value="2">Activate</option>
                    <option value="3">Connect</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button id='addaction' class="btn">Добавить действие</button></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And JQuery code:

```
$('#addaction').click(function() {
    $('.actions_body tr:not(:last)').clone()
      .insertBefore($('#table_actions tr:last'));
});

$('select[name=action_action]').change(function() {
    alert();
});
```

My problem: by changing selection in the **cloned part** of the table, there is no alert.

Comment: there is no error with this code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the `withDataAndEvents` boolean parameter:

```
$('.actions_body tr:not(:last)').clone(true)
```

> **.clone( [withDataAndEvents] )**
>
> withDataAndEventsA Boolean indicating whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements.

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because the change event is bound on page load, and the cloned elements are obvious not present at that time. You need to delegate the event handler to a parent. Try this:

```
$('#table_action').delegate('select[name=action_action]', 'change', function() {
    alert();
});
```

Alternatively you can pass a boolean parameter to `clone()` to clone the element with it's attached events.