# Add unlimited field forms and select from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to make a form to retrieve values from database. The form will have a date field AND/OR drop-down and a row of three fields as default. The user can add/remove extra rows as per required.
The three fields are:

- drop-down with options as table name from db(eg. employee_name,vehicle_name etc)
- drop-down for conditions (like/equal-to/greater-than etc)
- text-box where user can input data (eg. ford,suzuki etc).

How can I make a form where I can add/remove fields as required and then retrieve the values through a PHP code and use that as query to select and display appropriate values from database?

I use PHP Codeigniter method to build this custom search form.

[form image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/93336185@N06/8484142759/in/photostream)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Do you know javascritp/jQuery?

Comment: @ntgCleaner i have gone through this (http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/58/adding-unlimited-form-fields-with-jquery-mysql/) Its for inserting data

Comment: Perfect.  So your question is how to pull the info from the select table? If so, look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726443/jquery-clone-and-append

Comment: @ntgCleaner But I need this cloned values to be executes as database select statement

Comment: @ntgCleaner also I have different table name, condition and input value every time extra field is added.

Comment: Ah, I see.  If I'm understanding you correctly, you will have to make an ajax call.  Take a look into "jQuery .post"  You can make a php page that does the randomization (or call back and forth) every time a new line is made.  If you need more specifics, let me know.

Comment: @ntgCleaner i have edited the question and added a link to image of form

Comment: Ok, so you want a user to go to this page, input some variables from some dropdowns and some inputs, then create an entire query string from the user input?  I would suggest pulling all of the variables you need from PHP to populate the dropdown boxes first thing.  Then using a jquery script to append each of the fields into a query string which you can then use on your submit button to post-to-self (if you want the page to refresh there).  Correct?

Comment: @ntgCleaner yes thats what i want. filling up the drop-down i will try my best since php i have been working for a while. but how would i append the string using jquery. I'm very new regarding javascript/jquery.

Comment: Great, so here's a few steps that you may have to research. 1) using jQuery to append form fields in a form (.append()). 2) using php to loop through multiple form elements. 3) submit arrays.  I will look into this a bit, but I feel this will be the best way to go.  If you feel like you like jQuery a lot, look at .submit() as well.  This can change your php button into a jQuery submit button.

Comment: @ntgCleaner Thanks i ll research and get back soon